# How to convert binary private key file in to pem format which is acceptable by openssl

Tags: encryption, binary, openssl, file-conversion

I have a private key file which is in binary format. I need to convert it into `.pem` format. I am able to convert using base64 but `openssl` is not accepting this file. Is there any other way to convert binary to `.pem` which is acceptable by `openssl`.

Comment: There are 2.7 billion different binary formats for private key files.

Comment: Please add information about the precise binary format and your programming environment, or it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @GregS As your comment is now 14 hours old, is is out of date.  The current number is 2.9 billion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chances are you have a DER encoded key. To convert it you can (likely) do this

```
openssl rsa -inform der -in <yourfile> -outform pem -out output.pem
```

Please note that this will only work for unencrypted RSA private keys. If you have a DSA or EC (or PKCS8 formatted) key you'll need to change the command a bit, but you did not provide enough detail for me to narrow it down for you.

(There are also many other private key formats such as PVK, so if this still doesn't work please provide some more information)